# Help with using "only" in the context of temperature

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Could anyone please help me with saying: "It feels like...".
This is in the context of "I think the temperature was only 5 degrees, but it felt like negative 30!"

Could you also help me translate the entire sentence in this context, because I am unsure of it and probably only have a poor literal translation at this stage. Also how to use *only* in the sentence, because right now it is just "I think it was...".

My version:

> Ich denke die Temperatur war fünf Grad Celsius, aber ... (I need help with this part!)

Comment: Welcome to the forum, J Hardey, we've been waiting for you too long! However, be careful with translation requests, there's a risk to be put on hold and finally closed like [this](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/29295/20967). You may have a look at the [guidelines](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: There are several questions. It's interesting that the the first part of the body doesn't fit your title. The "real question" is a translation request. This is really on the verge of off-topic. At least you've provided an own attempt (if incomplete). For future questions, stay to one topic per question.

Answer (score 3):

This "I think" somewhat implies that you're guessing, and in the second sentence "it felt like" you're guessing again... is there any constant in your sentence? Also "only" doesn't really fit into this sentence either... (but you've somehow guessed that yourself).

Your sentence "I think...was only...it felt like..." would translate as

> Ich denke, die Temperatur war nur 5 Grad, aber es hat sich wie -30 (Minus 30) angefühlt!

but that - while being grammatically correct - doesn't sound like a fluent sentence.

I'd rather say

> The temperature was around 5 degrees, but it felt like 30 below (zero)!

which would translate to

> Es waren etwa 5 Grad, aber es hat sich angefühlt wie -30!

Comment: thank you for replying! I would also just like to ask in your preferred translation, you used 'waren etwa' I just don't understand the rule for this as I thought it was just 'war' could you please explain to me? I understand everything else thank you :)

Comment: hhmmmm... you got me thinking here, I used that instinctively - fortunately, I was correct ;-) "waren" is used in plural because it was more than a single degree (5 degrees in this case). "war" might probably also be correct - especially when used colloquially - as we are referring to "a (single) temperature". Check the Duden http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Grad (# 2).

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence

> I think the temperature was only 5 degrees, but it felt like negative
>   30!

would I translate like this:

> Die Temperatur lag wohl bei 5 Grad plus, aber gefühlt bei minus 30!

Or like this:

> Die Temperatur betrug wohl 5 Grad plus, aber gefühlt minus 30!

Comment: "gefühlt _bei_ minus 30" wouldn't be correct, but your other option is colloquially correct.

Comment: @Marakai: Why should "gefühlt bei minus 30" not be correct?

Comment: For one because,,colloquially, the form _gefühlt minus 30_ has made its way into common acceptance. For the other, _bei_ would have the meaning of _at_, which would feel awkward even in English : **the temperature was about 5 degrees plus, but it felt _at_ 30 minus**. _bei_ I would use in something like: **Er ertrug die Temperatur recht gut, und fühlte sie erst _bei_ minus 30**: he tolerated the temperature and only started to feel it at around minus 30

Comment: @Marakai: I may be wrong, but I don't see a problem if *bei* has the meaning of *at*, judge a remark like `Die Temperatur lag bei 5 Grad` to be correct.

Comment: actually once I ran it around my head a few time, you are  correct. Lack of caffeine or something, my apologies, but I can't edit my comment anymore. Ignore it with extreme prejudice! >.< (I did upvote your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would translate that to

```
Ich denke die Temperatur war fünf Grad Celsius, aber es kam mir vor wie minus 30!.
```